# A figure based \contentsname

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

In order to give my memoir based book a more professional look, I disabled the printout of chaptername, chapternumber and chapter title via the commands

```
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}

\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}

\chapter[TOC title][Header Title]{}
```

and in the beginning of each file I used the command

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{chapterTitle.eps}
\end{center}
```

where chapterTitle.eps was a figure saying for example

```
CHAPTER 1 INTRODUCTION
```

with the appropriate colors and positioning of the strings. Is it possible to do the same thing with the TOC, namely to disable the printing of

```
\contentsname
```

and display a figure-based version of it? I think that this would give to the TOC a more professional appearance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand what you want, then modify `\contentsname` along the lines of:

```
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\includegraphics{TocTitle.eps}}
```